# export excel file to SharePoint 2010 in DataSheet view using Perl

Tags: perl, sharepoint

i want to export Datasheet view from SharePoint to excel, modify it, and then import it back to SharePoint using Perl code.

so far, i succeed exporting to excel, can you help me with import it back to SharePoint?

Comment: What have you tried, and of that, what isn't working?

See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips on how to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me, though it is for sharepoint 2007.
http://www.squish.net/log/2008/10/11/perl-sharepoint/

Otherwise you can check out the api on microsofts site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587(v=office.14).aspx